# Can anyone help to id the component from la-d933p motherboard?

Tags: identification, components, motherboard

[image]

The component is placed on dell laptop la-d933p motherboard
And is connected to AON6992 mosfet

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the Richtek RT6585BGQW.
https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT6585A=RT6585B/DS6585AB-04.pdf